# How to set a country by default or remove country or region field from Stipe Checkout form?

Tags: stripe-payments

Setup:

- PHP 8
- Symfony 6

My project is available only in France. I had already collected the date related to the purchase (address) so I don’t want to ask neither allow the user to select another country than France. So I need to set a country by default to France in the Stipe Checkout form or remove the country or region field. I had checked the documentation for similar issues but I had not found any solution.

[image]

I'm open to suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

I tried to set a country by default so that a used can't be allowed to switch the country but that doesn't work.

Comment: It's not possible to remove this field. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845469/18343043)

Comment: were you able set the country?

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

**Instead of using just:**

```
PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration = new PaymentSheet.Configuration(MerchantName);
```

**You need to use:**

```
PaymentSheet.Address address = new PaymentSheet.Address.Builder() .country("FR") .build();
PaymentSheet.BillingDetails billingDetails = new PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder().address(address).build();
PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration =
                            new PaymentSheet.Configuration.Builder(MerchantName).defaultBillingDetails(billingDetails).build();
```